# How do I solve this Tablet code?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I have the following puzzle I am trying to solve from the online idle game [structure idle](http://structure.zefiris.su/).

[image: Tablet puzzle]

Previously, I had different types of puzzles in which I had lists of letter pairs to arrange, for example : AB, DC, CA -> DCAB. I thought this might be a similar type of puzzle, but I'm not really sure how to approach solving it. As far as I know, based on how the previous puzzles were done, the answer should be a string of letters with length 5.

Comment: Is there any sort of limitation for the final answer code? Does it have to be an English word, or a minimum/maximum length? Can it have letters and numbers, or only one of those?

Comment: @bobble as far as i know it should just be a string of letters, Im assuming the Code length at the top is how long the string will be

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> U D P N F

because

> each of the numbers can be decomposed into a product of two of the given digits there:
>
>  14 = 01×14 (DU) or 02×07 (LK)
>  880 = 11×80 (PN)
>  11 = 01 x 11 (PD)
>  2000 = 40 x 40 (AA) or 25 × 80 (FN)

And then you can

> choose a factorization that lets the overlapping numbers in the "code pattern" share a factor.
>  [image]
>  So the answer is **UDPNF**.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks.it ended up being the first order you mentioned, not the reverse. Also thanks for adding the graphic at the end with the text showing how you were chaining them, it wasnt clicking for me until i saw that

Comment: @Dragonrage Right, I hadn't used the graphic at first - forgot to remove the "reverse" part once I noticed that. Glad I could help!

Comment: Second Spoiler block first line got a error. rot13(Factorization got a third digit instead of two)

Comment: @masterX244 Fixed, thanks!